# Single Responsibility Principle and Service/Repository design

Tags: java, oop, encryption, single-responsibility-principle

I am wondering how to best separate responsibilites in the following example.

There is a `Foo` object that has some `id` and some `reallySecretImportantData` fields. Id is a simple identificator for referencing the object, while `reallySecretImportantData` is data that should be encrypted in the database, since the database is the only vulnerable point in this example.

Now, if we have a `FooService` with methods `void storeFoo(Foo foo)` and `Foo readFoo(Id id)`.

We also have a `FooRepository` that has standard CRUD methods which stores Foo objects in the database.

Now, since I'd like to save `reallySecretImportantData` encrypted, I have to encrypt is somewhere and decrypt it somewhere.

Since `FooRepository`s responsibility should not include crypto operations, the logical place is `FooService`.

Now, if I were in some development environment, I'd want, for dev&test purposes, to have the `reallySecretImportantData` saved in plain text.

Provided I use some sort of DI, I could write 2 implementations of my service, one for prod and other for dev/test, and just configure DI to use the prod one in production environment and dev/test in dev&test environment.

Now, if in any near future arises the request to change the way how `reallySecretImportantData` is stored, I could simply write another implementation of the service and use my DI framework to inject it.

Would this simple design be good enough for the current mock-up case?

Answer (score 1):

Your design recalls me [strategy pattern.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) `FooService` could be considered as a strategy interface.

But I prefer to add `encrypt()`and `decrypt()`methods to this interface instead of `store()` and  `read()`. We can name it as `FooCryptoStrategy`.

Moreover, `FooRepository` may be constructed with a `FooCryptoStrategy` object.
So, you can CRUD `Foo` objects not regarding encryption issues.
You can create several `FooCryptoStrategy` implementations for release and test. Even you can implement a `NonCryptoStrategy`.

In conclusion, using strategy pattern, we can assign one responsibility to one class: 
`Foo`: storing data 
`FooCryptoStrategy`: encrypt and decrypt `Foo` objects 
`FooRepository`: making Foo objects persistent. 
A controller class: creating concrete `FooCryptoStrategy` and `FooRepository` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a "service"?

Consider a `Secret` object that knows how to en/de/crypt, and a data management object that deals with persistence.

Make your functionality "pluggable" by implementing your encryption algorithms with a common interface, e.g. IEncrypt.  So for example you might have an AesEncryptor as well as a TestPlainEncryptor

```
// simple non-dependency-injection example    
Secret encrypted = new Secret(new AesEncryptor, "key", "my secret stuff");
new SecretDM().Save(s);

Secret retrieved = new SecretDM().Get("key");
// println(retrieved.Decrypt());
```

Comment: Well, the issue at hand is I am unable to change database schema. Another issue is, given your solution, I should somehow persist instance of IEncrypt interface, which is not something I'd want, nor I am sure is a good solution.